# Is there a way to expand the Overleaf spell check dictionary to include scientific dictionaries?

Tags: overleaf

I would like to include chemistry, math, and geology dictionaries rather than continuously adding entries to my personal dictionary. Alternatively, I'd like to turn the Overleaf spellcheck off entirely, so I can use a 3rd party browser add-on.

Is this functionality present?

Comment: I'd ask the Overleaf support if I were you.

Comment: Did you get a reply at all about this?

Comment: I am consistently disappointed with the words that are somehow not in the default dictionary.  Considering Overleaf is almost entirely used for scientific writing, it's bizarre that it seems to only include words from a children's dictionary.